# How can I delete a file/s after 60 seconds after it has been saved to the database?

Tags: c#

I need some assistance here.

In my console app when a file is added to a directory it then saves it in the database.  All of this works.  The problem I have though is that at the end of the week a new file will be added with the same name.

So when the files have been added to that folder it should then remove them after 60 seconds.

Here is the code I have but it is not working.

```
private static void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File created: {0}", e.Name);

        string connectionString = @"Data Source=Development-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FileDB;Integrated Security=True";
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        byte[] file;
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(e.FullPath))
        {
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
            file = reader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
        }
        //FileStream stream = new FileStream(e.Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        //BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        //byte[] file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
        //reader.Close();
        //stream.Close();
        DateTime dateTimeVariable = DateTime.Now;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FileTable (filename, filecontent, datestamp) VALUES (@filename, @filecontent, @datestamp)", connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@filename", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = info.Name;
            command.Parameters.Add("@filecontent", SqlDbType.VarBinary, int.MaxValue).Value = file;
            command.Parameters.Add("@datestamp", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimeVariable;
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Database");

        foreach (string filed in files)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filed);
            if (fi.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60))
                fi.Delete();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

It deletes it straight away instead of waiting 60 seconds

Comment: wrong if clause, should be `fi.CreateionTime.AddSeconds(60) < DateTime.Now`

Comment: DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60) would be 60 seconds into the future... I think you need 60 seconds into the past?

Comment: is it a good idea to put thread.sleep, just thinking ?

Comment: Are you really saving files into a database...?

Comment: @ Marco salemo,  Yes Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
 fi.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60)
```

Is of course always true. it should be this:

```
 fi.CreationTime.AddSeconds(60) < DateTime.Now
```

Comment: Its not deleting it straight away now but its not deleting at all now

Answer (score 0):

```
if (fi.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60))
```

should change to:

```
if (fi.CreationTime <= DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-60))
```

This is because you are currently checking if the creation time is before 60 seconds into the future (which it always will be). However, you should be checking whether the creation time was before, the current time minus 60 seconds.